# Как правильно в while использовать два условия?

Tags: php

Как правильно построить и такую конструкцию? Смысл - читать построчно из двух файлов и передавать каждую строку от каждого файла функции.

```
while (($textA = fgets($handle, 4096) !== false) && ($textB = fgets($handle2, 4096) !== false)) {   
    $arr = getTextDiff($textA, $textB, $delimeter = "\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Присвоение имеет самый низкий приоритет, поэтому у Вас сначала прочитается, сравнится и результат уйдёт в переменную.
Надо поставить скобки, чтобы сначала присвоить, а потом сравнить:

```
while ((($textA = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) && (($textB = fgets($handle2, 4096)) !== false)) {   
    $arr = getTextDiff($textA, $textB, $delimeter = "\n");
}
```